# How to get all the push notification payloads after an iOS app launches or did become active

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have an app to work on. And I need to know if there is already some push notifications before the app is opened. Is there a way to solving the issue?

Thanks

Comment: *I need to know if there is already some push notifications before the app is opened* If you get to execute any code before executing any code I belive you can nominate yourself as God. If what you mean is that when your app is opened then you must receive any previously sent notification, well, it's also impossible as you need to send to your server your push registration id in order to send messages to it, so your app must be already opened...

Answer (score 1):

You can't push a notification to a device when your application hasn't been opened at least once - the user has to authorize push notifications and you need get the push token value - returned after calling `registerForRemoteNotifications` - and send it to your server.

There's no guarantee that your app will see multiple push notifications if they all arrived when the application wasn't running. Often you'll just see the most recent notification. You should store all of the notifications on your server and have your application request them when it becomes active if there's at least one notification waiting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've registered for notifications you need to setup didReceiveRemoteNotification method in your AppDelegate.  There you can handle any information received from a Push Notification.  Here's a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) to there relevant documentation.